# Run command on new elevated window

Tags: powershell

I have some commands that require to run as admin.

The script I have calls for the credentials and opens a new admin powershell window.

The problem I'm facing here is that once open (the admin window), powershell doesn't run any of the commands and I was looking to understand on how to make them run on the new window.

Edit:

The script I'm running is this

```
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr
Invoke-Command -FilePath "C:\path\to\script.ps1" -Credential $cred -Computer localhost
```

Comment: So you want what you currently have, to run on a new window as elevated?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**
Execute your scripts with an account with administrator context/permissions.

██████████████████

**Solution 2**
Impersonate with the cmdlet ***Start-Process***

**Code - Script.ps1**

```
[string]$userName = 'Megam'
[string]$userPassword = '100'
[securestring]$secStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $userPassword -AsPlainText -Force
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($userName, $secStringPassword)
try {
    $Command = "./Script2.ps1"
    Start-Process pwsh "-NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command $Command" -Credential $Credentials -Wait
}
catch {
    $_.Exception.Message
}
```

**Code - Script2.ps1**

```
$username = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
Write-Host "HelloWorld!!! $username" -ForegroundColor Green
pause
```

**Output**
[image: 1]

Comment: I don't know what can I be doing wrong here but, I have replaced the username and password and put both scripts on the same folder and I'm getting the error: "this command cannot be run due to the error: the system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: Check the correct executable in Start-Process. For PowershellCore = pwsh.exe, for WindowsPowershell = powershell.exe

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked making that change to powershell.exe

Comment: I appreciate having helped you. Mark as accepted answer.